# Save Large Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

I have the following code that saves a large size image - I get an exception:

```
private void SaveImage(BitmapSource source, string OutPutPath)
    {
        source.Freeze();

        encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));

        Stream fileStream = File.Create(OutPutPath);

        try
        {
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
            encoder = null;
        }
    }
```

The exception is:

`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

The call stack shows:

`MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods.WICBitmapFrameEncode.WriteSource(SafeMILHandle THIS_PTR, SafeMILHandle pIBitmapSource, Int32Rect& r)
   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.SaveFrame(SafeMILHandle frameEncodeHandle, SafeMILHandle encoderOptions, BitmapFrame frame)
   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.Save(Stream stream)`

Comment: Is a file and doesn't exists. The size in pixels of the image is 23976 * 23976.

A smaller image 23976 * 12000 does not return the error and saves well.